# ¿Cómo especificar la ubicación donde Pipenv debe crear el entorno virtual?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Estoy en un windows y quiero que el entorno virtual que Pipenv (Paquete para Python) crea por defecto en la carpeta .virtualenvs en el directorio del usuario, lo cree en una carpeta que yo especifique.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearlo en el proyecto, fijando la variable de entorno:

```
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT="enabled"
```

Pero no hay un comando específico para crear en un directorio como puede tener `Anaconda` o `virtualenv`. La razón es que `pipenv` no es una herramienta para manejar distintos entornos. Puedes ver más en su [documentación](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: En windows el equivalente de `export` es `set`

Comment: Si quieres tener un entorno virtual localizado dentro de tu proyecto venv es muy sencillo de aprender y viene instalado en python por defecto